# get the url from which the ajax call has been made in the ajax function

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

For example, 
I have an `ajax` request from the page `http://www.abc.com/xyz/1` to the function controlling `ajax`.

Is there any way except sending it through the parameters so that I could know that in the function I can fetch `http://www.abc.com/xyz/1` and realise that the ajax request came from here?

Comment: Well, the question in not clear? Come again? See, you know the URL and then you are sending a request to the server right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the server wants to know from which page, or the server's location, then you can use this in the end, if PHP:

```
die($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
```

Comment: This is fetching me the uri to the ajax function not to the ajax call. Any other way?

Comment: Still don't get the question. Can you say an example? Like, www.example.com is firing an ajax call to ajax.example.com. Now what you wanna get and where?

Comment: Ya so in ajax.example.com i would like to get www.example.com. When I used your answer it gave me ajax.example.com

Comment: Aha... It should actually give www.example.com only, according to http://in.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Oh k. Maybe thats happening because I'm trying on localhost. Il try to put it online and check it out. Thanx

Comment: Let me know if my server runs on wp egnine with CDN with caches, will this HTTP_REFERER cached or something?

Answer (score 3):

you can get request url by using below php code:

```
 $request_url=( $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
```